# Item that is only accessible to the namespace

Tags: php

Is there a way to declare something so that only items within the same namespace can access that item?

```
namespace Space1;
internal class MyClass {
    public function Func(){}
}
```

**Example 1 (Error):**

```
// Global Space
use Space1\MyClass;
$class = new MyClass(); // Throws an error
```

**Example 2 (Error):**

```
namespace Space2;
use Space1\MyClass;
$class = new MyClass(); // Throws an error
```

**Example 3 (Valid):**

```
namespace Space1;
use Space1\MyClass;
function Test(){
    $class = new MyClass(); // No error
}
```

**Example 4 (Valid):**

```
namespace Space1\Subspace;
use Space1\MyClass;
function Test(){
    $class = new MyClass(); // No error
}
```

Comment: The question goes well with your nick...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there anyway to define public or private or protected classes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192154/is-there-anyway-to-define-public-or-private-or-protected-classes-in-php)

Comment: There is no and shouldn't be such a way, because namespaces don't solve a problem of access, but solve problems of names collisions and long names.

Comment: @Axalix C# has such a feature.

Comment: But your question is attributed with a php tag.

Comment: Right, I am saying if other languages have it why is it a bad feature?

Comment: Well, there is also no multiple inheritance in php. It's not bad or good, it's just different.

Comment: What is the problem that it solves? Could be there's a different way of approaching it in PHP. Also, you could try [detecting the calling namspeace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518842/determine-what-namespace-the-function-was-called-in) in the constructor and throw an exception.

Comment: Also please note that your assumption “only items within the same namespace” is not coherent with examples: `use` does not change current namespace, it is only an aliasing/importing method. Try to write `echo __NAMESPACE__;` inside your `Test()` function: you will obtain `Space1` even after `use Space1\MyClass;` Also, if you call `\Space1\MyClass\Test()` you will obtain a Fatal error.